# Incorrect date format using moment and web api request using .net core

Tags: javascript, c#, api, date

I want use moment to handle dates, but when i send request to web api url the date arrives in another format.

For example, from JS i send '2021-01-02' but when request arrive backend, the date transform to '02-01-2021' and i need handle the YYY-MM-DD format for backend

example request:

```
get(): Observable<any>{  
  let strDate = '2021-01-02';

  const payoad = {
     ... //other properties,
     datesearch: moment(strDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') // --> 2021-01-02
  }

  return this.http.post<any>('https://localhost:33421/api/orders', payload)  
}
```

My c# class request:

```
public class RequestDto
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datesearch { get; set; }
}
```

My web api controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Search(RequestDto request)
    {
        var datecheck = request.Datesearch; // -> this get '02-01-2021'
        ....
        ....
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

What I can be doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Solved it as follow: as I am working with net core, I had to set the culture info inside my SatrtUp.cs class -> Configure method

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
        customCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
      

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        { 
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(customCulture),
            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            { 
                customCulture
            },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            { 
                customCulture
            }
        });

         ......
         ......
     }
```

Comment: For me,your code worked well.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do is to change

```
'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

to

```
'YYYY-MMM-DD'
```

That way it avoids ambiguity and c# DateTime can parse it easily.

ie. 05-06-20 could be 6-May-2020 or 5-June-2020
It's easier to use letters for the month

Comment: This "answer" seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @RobG Usually the reason people worry about the order of the date parts is because of the difference between US and European date formats, which can cause parsing errors. This is eliminated if the month is in letters. After that C# can print the correct date in any form you like.

Comment: @RobG It's also possible that I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Not worked for me, the request throw 400 (bad request) with format 'YYYY-MMM-DD'

Comment: @AlonsoContreras reverse the order and make sure capitaliztion is right. probably 'dd MMM yyyy'